# C++ CUDA Thrust vector polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, cuda, polymorphism, thrust

In the program I am writing right now I want use either GPU or CPU to compute (for benchmarking one against other). To do this I would like to have some universal pointer which I could initialize with an instance of device_vector or host_vector like this:

```
ptr = new host_vector<float>();
```

or

```
ptr = new device_vector<float>();
```

Both host_vector and device_vector inherit from detail::vector_base but I can't use a pointer of detail::vector_base because vector_base (which means device_vector and host_vector too) is a template class where template has two arguments - the type it contains and the allocator it uses. Both kinds of vectors  use different allocators, which in turn means two different pointers.

Is there any way to define ptr so I can use it like in my examples?

Comment: Can't you template the benchmark code and just create separate instances for host_vector and device_vector? Why are pointers necessary?

Comment: The answer here is most likely to do the same thing Thrust does, i.e. use compile time polymorphism.

Comment: @talonmies  Two reasons: 1) I want to fall-back to CPU code if GPU doesn't have required functionality 2) I would like to give user a choice of computing device from GUI

Comment: @IdeaHat I want to decide at runtime (see above)

Comment: I don't know thrust very well but do thrust algorithms not take iterator pairs as std algorithms does? Iterators on vectors are commonly random access and nothing more than pointers. So you might be able to keep your benchmark generic and wrap host_ and device_vector in some sort of supercontainer which just gives you begin and end iterators.

Comment: Your response to @talonmies doesn't make sense.  The suggestion is that you write the code once, template-ing it for either host or device vector, and *instantiate both code paths in your program*.  Then make your runtime decision and choose code path accordingly.  I don't see any reason why that suggestion wouldn't work, based on what you've described so far.  It would allow you to fall-back to CPU code at runtime, and it would allow the user to make a runtime choice of computing "device".

Comment: [Here's an example](http://pastebin.com/fqN6N0gM) of what I interpeted @talonmies comment to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up combining @Michael Haidl 's and @Robert Crovella 's (and by proxy @talonmies ') suggestions to create a class (called it "UnifiedVector") which has two specializations based on a non-type parameter enum (ComputeMethod::GPU, ComputeMethod::CPU).

In one specialization UnifiedVector inherits host_vector and in the other device_vector. Then I template the classes that use UnifiedVector using the same enum so I can use it like that:

```
template<ComputeMethod C>
class SomeClass
{
  private:
      UnifiedVector<something,C> data;
}
```

Not sure how elegant or "right" this approach is, but I guess it'll suffice since it achieves the goal of making the vector "transparent" to the class thah uses it (as in it doesn't have to explicitely treat one kind of vector in different way or hold two pointers for two different possible vector types).